# Hololens Device Portal Kiosk Mode web api

Tags: hololens

I am building a tool in which I am using windows device portal wrapper in order to connect and access hololen's device portal.

I would like to be able to get/set kiosk mode from my tool so I dont need to go to device portal and do it manually.

Windows device portal wrapper doesnt give any functionality to access kiosk mode though.

Does anyone know the web api path for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So since it looks like you're building a tool for converting HoloLens into Kiosks, you need to do this at scale. If you are looking to create a different method of converting your HoloLens into Kiosks, I think you should go provisiong packages.

Provisioning packages will let you make a package you can keep applying to multiple HoloLens. Also some companies don't like enabling developer mode, and this is a method that doesn't have a security risk. Also device portal only allows a single app Kiosk, where as you could create a Multi app Kiosk if you wanted using other methods.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-kiosk#set-up-kiosk-mode-using-a-provisioning-package-windows-10-version-1803

Do this help things? I know it's not actually what you were looking for, but hopefully it helps. It it doesn't let me know, I might have a different potential solution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
Its not what I am looking for
I will apply kiosk mode through provisioning package initially
But after this I want to be able to turn on/off the kiosk mode through my tool
I need the REST API call to the device portal in order to update the kiosk mode

Comment: @user2525557 I see. I think the easiest solution to that is actually using multiple accounts. Simply have 1 account set to be the user logon type for the Kiosk mode. Then another account not. The account not designated for Kiosk mode should have full access to the shell. This gives you a sort of IT account Kiosk worker account set up.  
Does that help?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.
In my scenario though, if I dont find the REST API to set kiosk mode by code then I will just do it manually through device portal. 
thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Kiosk Mode can be set via Device Portal’s REST API by doing a POST to /api/holographic/kioskmode/settings with one required query string parameter (“kioskModeEnabled” with a value of “true” or “false”) and one optional parameter (“startupApp” with a value of a package name).  Please keep in mind that Device Portal is intended for developers only and should not be enabled on non-developer devices.  The REST API is subject to change in future updates/releases.